# Retrofit onResponse method Not Executing

Tags: android, api, model, retrofit, pojo

```
    import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;


interface ApiInterface {


    @POST("doctorCategories.php")
    Call<List<DoctorModel>> getDoctorModel();
}
```

Here is the Main Calling

```
...
mport androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class DoctorListRecycler extends AppCompatActivity {
    DoctorAdapter retrofitAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_list_recycler);
        fetchJSON();
    }
    private void fetchJSON(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://svinothadapitest/doctorpat/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        ApiInterface api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<DoctorModel>> call = api.getDoctorModel();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DoctorModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<DoctorModel>> call, Response<List<DoctorModel>> response) {
            Log.i("Responsestring", response.body().toString());
            Toast.makeText(DoctorListRecycler.this, "Hi" +call, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(DoctorListRecycler.this, "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("onSuccess", response.body().toString());

                    String jsonresponse = response.body().toString();
                    writeRecycler(jsonresponse);

                } else {
                    Log.i("onEmptyResponse", "Returned empty response");//Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Nothing returned",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<DoctorModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(DoctorListRecycler.this, "Failure Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    }
    private void writeRecycler(String response){
        try {
            //getting the whole json object from the response
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            // if(obj.optString("status").equals("true")){
            ArrayList<DoctorModel> modelRecyclerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray dataArray  = obj.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                DoctorModel modelRecycler = new DoctorModel();
                JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // modelRecycler.setImgURL(dataobj.getString("imgURL"));
                modelRecycler.setName(dataobj.getString("Name"));
                modelRecycler.setSpecialist(dataobj.getString("Dermatologist"));
                modelRecycler.setAddress(dataobj.getString("Address"));
                modelRecyclerArrayList.add(modelRecycler);
            }

            retrofitAdapter = new DoctorAdapter(this,modelRecyclerArrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(retrofitAdapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

            //}else {
            //     Toast.makeText(DoctorListRecycler.this, obj.optString("message")+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //}

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
...
```

Pojo Class

...

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class DoctorModel {
    @SerializedName("sno")
    private String sno;
    @SerializedName("Doctorid")
    private String Doctorid;
    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String Name;
    @SerializedName("Password")
    private String Password;
    @SerializedName("mobileno")
    private String mobileno;
    @SerializedName("Specialist")
    private String Specialist;
    @SerializedName("Experience")
    private String Experience;
    @SerializedName("Address")
    private String Address;
    @SerializedName("rating")
    private String rating;

    public DoctorModel() {
    }

    public DoctorModel(String name, String specialist, String address, String rating) {
        Name = name;
        Specialist = specialist;
        Address = address;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public DoctorModel(String sno, String doctorid, String name, String password, String mobileno, String specialist, String experience, String address, String rating) {
        this.sno = sno;
        Doctorid = doctorid;
        Name = name;
        Password = password;
        this.mobileno = mobileno;
        Specialist = specialist;
        Experience = experience;
        Address = address;
        this.rating = rating;
    }


    public String getSno() {
        return sno;
    }

    public void setSno(String sno) {
        this.sno = sno;
    }

    public String getDoctorid() {
        return Doctorid;
    }

    public void setDoctorid(String doctorid) {
        Doctorid = doctorid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }

    public String getMobileno() {
        return mobileno;
    }

    public void setMobileno(String mobileno) {
        this.mobileno = mobileno;
    }

    public String getSpecialist() {
        return Specialist;
    }

    public void setSpecialist(String specialist) {
        Specialist = specialist;
    }

    public String getExperience() {
        return Experience;
    }

    public void setExperience(String experience) {
        Experience = experience;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}
...
```

Adapter Class
...

```
import android.content.Context;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        public class DoctorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DoctorAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
            private LayoutInflater inflater;
            private ArrayList<DoctorModel> dataModelArrayList;

            public DoctorAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<DoctorModel> dataModelArrayList) {
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
                this.dataModelArrayList = dataModelArrayList;
            }

            @Override
            public DoctorAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_doctor, parent, false);
                MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
                return holder;
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(DoctorAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
                //Picasso.get().load(dataModelArrayList.get(position).getImgURL()).into(holder.iv);
                holder.name.setText(dataModelArrayList.get(position).getName());
                holder.Specialist.setText(dataModelArrayList.get(position).getSpecialist());
                holder.address.setText(dataModelArrayList.get(position).getAddress());
                holder.rating.setText(dataModelArrayList.get(position).getRating());
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return dataModelArrayList.size();
            }

            class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

                TextView name, Specialist, address, rating;
                //ImageView iv;

                public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);

                    name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    Specialist = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Specialist);
                    address = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
                    rating = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
                    //iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv);
                }

            }
        }
...
```

json output is 
...

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "sno": "1",
            "Doctorid": "200",
            "Name": "Rai A",
            "Password": "1234",
            "mobileno": "9500012758",
            "Specialist": "Dermatologist",
            "Experience": "38",
            "Address": "21/22 Greams Lane, \nThousand Lights, Off Greams Ro",
            "rating": "4"
        },
        {
            "sno": "2",
            "Doctorid": "201",
            "Name": "Shraa M",
            "Password": "3242",
            "mobileno": "9962222923",
            "Specialist": "Diabetologist",
            "Experience": "45",
            "Address": "No. 21, Greams Lane,Off, Chennai",
            "rating": "5"
        }]
}
```

...

Any one can help me that im getting onFailure message each time im establishing on Response Connection in Retrofit.
Im try to rectify this error for the past four hours but i couldn't find it...
Please help me ......Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getData() {


    RetrofitClient.getClient().getinfo(Constants.Api_key)
            .enqueue(new Callback<BellmanResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<BellmanResponse> call, 
     Response<BellmanResponse> response) {


                    if ("success".equals(response.body().getMessage())) {

                       ////////

                    } else {

                        ////////////

                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<BellmanResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    //////////

                }
            });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onFailure` means that you have no response. Either because you have no internet connection, or you are pinging to the wrong server.

Some problem could also be from your GSON converter but, it's not the case here.

So I Can say that till now, I see you're pinging to a wrong server 

`https://svinothadapitest/doctorpat/`, which will certainly callback to `onFailure`

Comment: I got answer its not server mistake.Response that return is json array(Array name is "data") but i write the code to receive the response in List. After remove the data now i got the answer.That is the mistake i did.Thank u all for supporting me